# TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm pretty new to both Node and Firebase, but can't seem to find this error online.

I get the following error when I try to load Firebase Database through Firebase Admin:

TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function
DatabaseService../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js.DatabaseService.getDatabase
node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/database/database.js:62

```
    var db = this.INTERNAL.databases[dbUrl];
    if (typeof db === 'undefined') {
        var rtdb = require('@firebase/database');
        db = rtdb.initStandalone(this.appInternal, dbUrl).instance;
        this.INTERNAL.databases[dbUrl] = db;
    }
    return db;
```

Node Module Versions:
Firebase-Admin@5.8.0
@firebase/app@0.1.1
@firebase/database@0.1.3

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use both the Firebase Admin SDK and the Firebase web client SDK in the same program.  That's probably not what you want.  If you're writing server code, just use the admin SDK and don't bother with the client SDK.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the response. According to package.json, firebase-admin holds firebase-database as a dependancy - I don't think I've installed firebase web client, but can't be sure... I did try adding firebase as a core package and update to try to fix the above problem originally (but obviously to no avail).

Comment: I've tried reimporting all package for the project from scratch including firebase-admin, react, react-dom, react-scripts (through create-react-app), and react-router, but the same error is occurring.

Comment: Don't use the client SDKs directly in server side code, even if you see them as part of your node modules.  Use the admin SDK only.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: I should have read the docs better - looks like i was using admin SDK when I should have been using web client SDK the entire time.

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone has the same issue I did:

@firebase/database/package.json:

```
"main": "dist/cjs/index.node.js",
"browser": "dist/cjs/index.js",
"module": "dist/esm/index.js",
```

`initStandalone()` is in `dist/cjs/index.node.js` but not `dist/esm/index.js` because it's only used serverside, not in the browser.

If you use webpack to bundle your code, even with `target: 'node'`, it will prefer "module" over "main" and use the file intended for the browser.

The solution for me was to set `resolve.mainFields` to `["main", "module"]` in webpack config.

PS. I'm using webpack to prepare my code for upload to AWS Lambda. If I don't use it I have to upload the entire node_modules folder which is huge and often causes timeouts on upload. I only need 10% of the code that's in there. If anyone knows of a better solution I'm keen to hear it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!  Finally ended an hours-long headache for me!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for this answer. Still saving the day in 2019 :)