# Use Firebase SDK with Netlify Lambda Functions

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda, netlify

I create a project that uses React + Firebase + Lambda Functions.

I have Firebase code on the front end and I needed a bit of back-end to handle some events. ([Prevent users from modifying data in Firebase but allow this data to be updated by the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499477/prevent-users-from-modifying-data-in-firebase-but-allow-this-data-to-be-updated))

As I use Netlify to deploy my app, I have access to Amazon Lambda Functions with netlify-lambda. (https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/)

Usually everything just works (mailchimp API, snipcart API etc ...)

But I can not get Firebase working.

I created a service account with the rights to write and read.

Here the code of my lambda function:
(Just a test to try to see the users section of the database.)

```
import firebaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin'
const serviceAccount = require('../utils/FirebaseServiceAccountKey.json')

export function handler (event, context, callback) {
  firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: 'https://sample-3615.firebaseio.com'
  })

  const db = firebaseAdmin.database()
  const ref = db.ref('/users')
  let users = {}

  ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
    users = snapshot.val()
  })

  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ users })
  })
}
```

It returns me : `TypeError: rtdb.initStandalone is not a function`.

I also have many Warning like this: `Module not found: Error: Can not resolve 'memcpy'` and for other packages too.

My call to the function in a Component:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    this.setState({loading: true})
    fetch('/.netlify/functions/score')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json.users))
      .then(() => this.setState({loading: false}))
  }
```

I'm not sure where the problem comes from. Webpack?

Comment: Have you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290136/5861618)?

Comment: OK thanks! I tried this solution. I modified the webpack config as indicated in the post but unfortunately it does not work with Gatsby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not been able to run the SDK with AWS Lambda from Netlify.

To use Firebase from Netlify Lambda Functions I am going through the REST API with admin privileges.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

It works perfectly like that.

```
import { google } from 'googleapis'
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
const serviceAccount = require('../utils/FirebaseServiceAccountKey.json')

const scopes = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database'
]

// Authenticate a JWT client with the service account.
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
  serviceAccount.client_email,
  null,
  serviceAccount.private_key,
  scopes
)

export function handler (event, context, callback) {
  const res = JSON.parse(event.body)
  // Use the JWT client to generate an access token.
  jwtClient.authorize(async function (error, tokens) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error making request to generate access token:', error)
    } else if (tokens.access_token === null) {
      console.log('Provided service account does not have permission to generate access tokens')
    } else {
      const accessToken = tokens.access_token
      const score = await fetch(`https://example-3615.firebaseio.com/scores/${res.uid}/score.json`)
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(score => score + res.score)

      fetch(`https://example-3615.firebaseio.com/scores/${res.uid}.json?access_token=${accessToken}`, {
        body: JSON.stringify({ score, displayName: res.user.displayName, photoURL: res.user.photoURL }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        method: 'PATCH'
      })
        .then(() => {
          callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: 'Score +1'
          })
        })
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in "webpack.server.js" configuration file. netlify-lambda used to bundle the server-side code (function code) and for some reasons, it bundles it incorrectly.
so i added new file to the project root "webpack.server.js":

```
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const pkg = require('./package')
const GenerateJsonPlugin = require('generate-json-webpack-plugin')


const externals = [
    'firebase-admin'
]

const genPackage = () => ({
    name: 'functions',
    private: true,
    main: 'index.js',
    license: 'MIT',
    dependencies: externals.reduce(
    (acc, name) =>
        Object.assign({}, acc, {
        [name]:
            pkg.dependencies[name] ||
            pkg.devDependencies[name]
        }),
    {}
    )
})


module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    resolve: {
        mainFields: ['module', 'main']
    },
    externals: externals.reduce(
        (acc, name) => Object.assign({}, acc, { [name]: true }),
        {}
    ),
    plugins: [new GenerateJsonPlugin('package.json', genPackage())]
}
```

this file config will create a new package.json file placed in lambda dist.

**UPDATE**
check my post on Medium ([Firebase Admin with Netlify lambda functions](https://medium.com/@saphidev/use-firebase-admin-with-netlify-lambda-functions-free-483d3b390e3a))