# How do I avoid initialising firebase when I'm running jest tests?

Tags: typescript, firebase, jestjs, slack-api

I'm writing jest unit tests for my slack bot event handler functions. I'm *not* testing interaction with the database; I've mocked the function which calls the database, so no actual database calls happen during the tests.

However, because firebase initialised in `firebase.ts` which is imported into `index.ts`, the test suite fails to run because jest doesn't have the correct environment variables.

What I want to achieve is a way of not instantiating the database at all, when I'm running tests. I've looked at some options for mocking firebase (eg npm packages such `ts-mock-firebase`, `firebase-mock`, and more manual approach using some other SO answers), but I haven't had any success with them.

So, is there a safe, reasonable way I can stop the database from instantiating during tests? It feels like this should be easy - maybe I'm missing something obvious!

I'm really surprised there doesn't seem to be a kind of community accepted solution to this problem as far as I can tell. Maybe I'm wrong and I've been looking in the wrong places?

Thanks for any wisdom you can offer!

`folder structure`

```
  - index.ts
  database
    - firebase.ts
  services
    - events.ts
    - events.test.ts
```

`index.ts`

```ts
import { loadEnv } from "./config/dotenv";
loadEnv();

import "./database/firebase";

// some app config here...

export app = new App(appOptions);
```

`firebase.ts`

```ts
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import firebaseServiceKey from "../config/firebaseServiceKey";

admin.initializeApp({
  // current required type appears to be wrong so has to be cast as any
  credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseServiceKey as any),
  databaseURL:
    process.env.FIREBASE_URL || "https://loopin-c782d.firebaseio.com",
});

export const auth = admin.auth();

export const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

`events.ts`

```ts
/**
 * A user renames the organization name in slack
 */
export const handleTeamRename = async (
  userId: string,
  token: string
): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const team = await getSlackTeam(token, userId);
    await updateOrganizationName(team.id, team.name, team.icon.image_230);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("team_rename event");
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

`events.test.ts`

```ts
import * as events from "./Events";
import * as dbOrganizations from "../database/Organizations";
import * as dbSlack from "../database/Slack";
import { SlackGeneratedTeam } from "../models/Slack";


describe("events", () => {
  const fakeBotToken = "xoxb-123abc";
  const fakeOrgId = "fakeOrgId";
  const fakeOrgName = "Mega Corp, inc.";
  const fakeUrl = "www.example.com";
  const fakeSlackTeam = {
    id: fakeOrgId,
    name: fakeOrgName,
    icon: {
      image_230: fakeUrl,
    },
  };

  describe("handleTeamRename", () => {
    let mockGetSlackTeam: jest.SpyInstance<
      Promise<SlackGeneratedTeam>,
      [token: string, id: string]
    >;
    let mockUpdateOrganizationName: jest.SpyInstance<
      Promise<void>,
      [id: string, displayName: string, photoUrl: string]
    >;

    beforeEach(() => {
      mockGetSlackTeam = jest.spyOn(dbSlack, "getSlackTeam").mockImplementation(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
        async (token: string, id: string) => fakeSlackTeam as SlackGeneratedTeam
      );
      mockUpdateOrganizationName = jest
        .spyOn(dbOrganizations, "updateOrganizationName")
        .mockImplementation(
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
          async (id: string, displayName: string, photoUrl: string) => {
            return;
          }
        );
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      mockGetSlackTeam.mockRestore();
      mockUpdateOrganizationName.mockRestore();
    });

    it("should make the right calls", async () => {
      void (await events.handleTeamRename(fakeOrgId, fakeBotToken));
      await expect(mockGetSlackTeam).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      await expect(mockGetSlackTeam).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        fakeBotToken,
        fakeOrgId
      );
      await expect(mockUpdateOrganizationName).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      await expect(mockUpdateOrganizationName).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        fakeOrgId,
        fakeOrgName,
        fakeUrl
      );
    });
  });
});
```

`error`

```shell
 npm run test events

> api@1.0.0 test
> jest "events"

 FAIL  src/services/Events.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Service account object must contain a string "project_id" property.

       6 | admin.initializeApp({
       7 |   // current required type appears to be wrong so has to be cast as any
    >  8 |   credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseServiceKey as any),
         |                                ^
       9 |   databaseURL:
      10 |     process.env.FIREBASE_URL || "[my firebase url]",
      11 | });

      at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:43:28)
      at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:89:28)
      at new FirebaseAppError (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:124:28)
      at new ServiceAccount (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:135:19)
      at new ServiceAccountCredential (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:69:15)
      at Object.cert (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential.js:113:54)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/database/firebase.ts:8:32)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.154 s, estimated 4 s
Ran all test suites matching /events/i.
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `firebase.ts` like below - notice the `if (!admin.apps.length)` check before initialising the admin:

```js
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import firebaseServiceKey from "../config/firebaseServiceKey";

if (!admin.apps.length) { /** See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764002/2516673 */
  admin.initializeApp({
    // current required type appears to be wrong so has to be cast as any
    credential: admin.credential.cert(firebaseServiceKey as any),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_URL || "https://loopin-c782d.firebaseio.com",
  });
}

export const auth = admin.auth();
export const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

Then you just need to mock `admin.apps` at the beginning of your `events.test.ts` file:

```js
jest.mock("firebase-admin", () => {
  return {
    apps: ["testAppId"], /** this array should not be empty, so firebase-admin won't try to load a certificate when running unit tests */
    auth: jest.fn(),
    firestore: jest.fn(),
  };
});

describe(...);
```

Now not only you can mock your admin, but you're also possibly avoiding [a known issue with multiple initialisation calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57764002/2516673).

Comment: Thanks for this Fapaz, I'll give it a go.